# Use functionality from native Android BluetoothHeadset class in Xamarin

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin.android, xamarin, android-bluetooth

We are trying to write a Xamarin application that will work with Handsfree-enabled bluetooth accessory.

The functionality we need for reading the commands raised by an accessory is located in a native Android class: [BluetoothHeadset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html).

Is there a way we can hook into the events that are monitored by instances of this class from our monodroid application?